# Is there a way to get Instagram public accounts stories using API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I’m trying to get any public qccount stories using instagram API. But I couldn’t find any documentation about that in the official graph website.

Answer (score 0):

This is available now, but only if the user authorizes your app. The user's account would also need to be an Instagram Business Account or Creator Account's

refer this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/stories/

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Dhanush, for my personal account I could get stories. but I would like to also download any public instagram account is thisd even possible with API ?